# Binding a database table but not show the data inside a datagridview table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to bind a DGV to a particular table but don't want to have it display the data that is in the table (only using it for insert queries) but I cannot figure out how to actually accomplish this in C#. Here is the code I have (but again, I don't want any data to be shown, just the column names, so just ignore the select query, it's there to explain what I want fetched).

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"])
   {
       // set the data source and bind to childrens table
       this.dbcmd = this.dbconn.CreateCommand();

       this.dbcmd.CommandText = "SELECT first_name, last_name, birthday, email FROM children";

       this.dt = new DataTable();

       this.da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(this.dbcmd); // don't want this either I think

       this.da.Fill(this.dt); // this I know I do not want

       this.bindingSource = new BindingSource();

       this.bindingSource.DataSource = this.dt;

       dataGridViewChildren.DataSource = this.bindingSource;

   }
}
```

Does this make any sense? I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information, I will try to provide more if more is needed.

Appreciate any help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the DataTable's DefaultView's Row Filter property to only show user added rows.

I did this by adding a column to the DataTable that sets all of your queried rows to false. Then any time a row is added to the DataTable from there on it gets set with true. I set the new column to not be displayed.

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserAdded", typeof(bool)));
foreach (var row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
    row["UserAdded"] = false;

bindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridViewChildren.DataSource = bindingSource;
dataGridViewChildren.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().Last().Visible = false;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "UserAdded = true";

dt.TableNewRow += (s, e) =>
{
    e.Row["UserAdded"] = true;
};
```

When the insert button is clicked you can get the rows the user added with...

```
var rows = dataGridViewChildren.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow);
```

Comment: I just want it to be bound to a particular table but not fill the dgv with the data, just be bound to it so I can insert. Does that make sense? For example, inserting numerous rows when the row(s) are clicked on inside of the dgv and after the user is done, insert all the rows.

Comment: @user2101411 insert what into what? Does this answer not work for you?

Comment: insert the filled out rows into the table upon completion.

Comment: @user2101411 insert user added rows into a database table?

Comment: Okay, so the user is going to insert values into the database via the DGV (can add, edit, delete rows). Once a user is done filling out rows inside, they click the insert button and it will update the table. Does that make sense? Oh, by the way, your answer did work, I just want to be sure I can then insert all the values filled out inside to the database.

Comment: I don't know if this is related but I cannot get to a next row, the row disappears and I'm back on the 1st one.

Comment: @user2101411 I have updated my answer. I hope this works well for you, if not just comment again!

Comment: would `var rows = dataGridViewChildren.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => !r.IsNewRow);` get each row value? Like how would I perform an insert query on this?

Comment: Have you done an insert like this before? Relative to this question, inserting seems a little out of scope. You can get access to the data like this, but if you need help inserting then I would recommend some more research on it or asking another question.

Comment: I'm not even sure on what to ask or research for this.. still learning

Comment: You can just loop through each row and do a simple insert like you did for your select statement. Something like `INSERT INTO (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (row.Cells[0].Value, row.Cells[1].Value, ...)` but of course use parameters in the sql instead of the values like row.Cells[0].Value. If that doesn't make sense then you'll definitely have to research more by searching "C# SQL Insert". Much too complicated to explain in comments.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed to know, I know how to insert I just am not too familiar with LINQ yet